# How to find all solutions of the equation $\sin x+\cos x=0$ which belong to $(-\pi, \pi)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, roots

Could you please help me understand and answer this question?

> Find all  the  solutions of this equation 
>   $$
> \sin x+\cos x=0
> $$
>    which belong  to  the interval $(-π; π)$

#### Progress

Divided by $\cos x$, got $\tan x=-1$.

Comment: Divide both sides by $\cos(x)$, and re-arrange to a tangent.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma, I did what you said and got $$\tan x=-1$$ is that my answer?

Comment: Now you look at the graph of $\tan x$ and see for what $x \in (-\pi,\pi)$ we have that $\tan x = -1$. These $x$ are what you want.

Comment: Hmm, okay, thanks. One question; how can we find $$-\pi$$ on the trigonometric circle?

Comment: It's the same as $\pi$, as $-\pi + 2\pi = \pi$.

Comment: On the unit circle we can see which $x$ have $\sin(x) = -\cos(x)$, it's the intersection with the line $y = -x$. This gives two angles.

Comment: Thank you for your response :)

Comment: Hint (for an alternative method without tan): -sin(x)=sin(-x). And cos(x)=sin(pi/2-x)

Comment: You may too rewrite this as $\sqrt{2}\sin(x+?)\;$ with $\sin(?)=\cos(?)=\frac 1{\sqrt{2}}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's quite straightforward:
$$0 = \sin x + \cos x = \frac1{2i}(e^{i x}-e^{-i x})+\frac12(e^{i x}+e^{-i x}),$$
multiplying by $2ie^{i x}$ gives an equivalent form
$$0=e^{2i x}-1+ie^{2i x}+i\iff 1-i=e^{2i x}(i+1)\iff e^{2 i x}=\frac{1-i}{i+1}=\frac{-i(i+1)}{i+1}=-i=e^{-i\pi/2},$$
which is true if and only if $2ix = -i\pi/2+2i\pi k\iff x=-\pi/4+\pi k$ for some $k\in\mathbb Z$, so the only solutions inside the interval are $x=-\pi/4$ and $x=3\pi/4$.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: $\sin x + \cos x = 0$ if and only if $\sin x = -\cos x$ if and only if $\tan x = -1$.